# Selectize js - проблемы со вставкой картинок

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Всем привет.
Столкнулась с проблемой. На сайте установлен selectize js. При попытки добавления картинок в option у select ничего не происходит. Подскажите можно ли как-то отключить этот плагин для конкретного select'a или как-то сделать так, чтобы картинки вставлялись?

```
<select id="country" class="form-control">
          <option value="ru"><img src="./images/197373-country-flags/svg/044-russia.svg">Россия +7</option>
          
          <option value="kz"><img src="/images/197373-country-flags/svg/229-kazakhstan.svg">Казахстан +7</option>
          <option value="kg"><img src="/images/197373-country-flags/svg/053-kyrgyzstan.svg">Кыргызстан +996</option>
          <option value="uz"><img src="/images/197373-country-flags/svg/041-uzbekistán.svg">Узбекистан  +998</option>
          <option value="tg"><img src="/images/197373-country-flags/svg/025-tajikistan.svg">Таджикистан  +992</option>
          <option value="tr"><img src="/images/197373-country-flags/svg/069-turkmenistan.svg">Туркменистан  +993</option>
          <option value="other">Другая </option>
          
        </select>
```

Код если кого-то интересует.

P.S гугл не помог, надеюсь на ваше понимание.

Comment: *Подскажите можно ли как-то отключить этот плагин для конкретного select'a* - можно. Как это поможет показать картинки? Стандартный  `select` не умеет показывать картинки.

Comment: Это понятно, просто в  тег засунуть  img. Каким образом отключать?

Comment: `$("#country")[0].selectize.destroy();` - вот так можно отключить. Но как вам это поможет?